# When "a" before plural form can be used?

Tags: indefinite-articles

On BBC website I have read the article "[Coronavirus: How to open a hairdressers after lockdown](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-52529820)". Why is "a" particle used before plural form of a noun? Isn't that incorrect?

Comment: hairdresser's, that's it.

Comment: As per the previous comment, the sentence in the question is a mistake. It shouldn't be a plural; it should be a possessive with an apostrophe.

Comment: So it's ok to skip apostrophe in the title in English?

Comment: @dzieciou: Even news organizations sometimes make typos. That doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: the actual noun is missing/implied. The noun should be shop or business. The hairdresser's (missing the apostrophe erroneously) is a adjective qualifier.